# How can I enable SSE-S3 (AES-256) encryption in cyberduck CLI?

Tags: amazon-s3, cyberduck

I am attempting to use cyberduck CLI to transfer files to an Amazon S3 bucket which requires AES-256 server side encryption for uploads.

While I can find the setting for this in the cyberduck GUI I can't seem to find any method of enabling upload encryption in the cyberduck CLI.

Does cyberduck CLI even support SSE? If so how can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cyberduck CLI does in fact support SSE-S3 (AES-256) encryption. According to their support it can be enabled by doing the following:

•   On macOS: Execute the command *defaults write ch.sudo.cyberduck s3.encryption.algorithm AES256*.

•   On Windows: Open or create the *default.properties* file in *%AppData%\Cyberduck* and add the line *s3.encryption.algorithm=AES256*